# React JS - Different front-end results on simulator/real phone

Tags: android, sdk, simulator, react.js, frontend

I'm having a issue with the front end results on Android Studio simulator. There's different front-end results between the simulator and real phone, even matching the screen dimensions and Android version. Different spacings between the buttons, labels and etc.

I can't post any print screens, because it's an internal project of the company that I work.

I'm using the SDK React Native 34 for code!